# How to add watermark to an animated gif image using jimp javascript?

Tags: javascript, npm, gif, animated-gif, jimp

These are my codes I used for adding watermark to an image:

```
    const ORIGINAL_IMAGE = "https://example/sample_image;
    const LOGO = fs.readFileSync('gangle.png');
    const LOGO_MARGIN_PERCENTAGE = 5;

    let [image, logo] = await Promise.all([
      Jimp.read(ORIGINAL_IMAGE),
      Jimp.read(LOGO)
    ]);

    logo.resize(image.bitmap.width, Jimp.AUTO);

    const xMargin = (image.bitmap.width * LOGO_MARGIN_PERCENTAGE) / 100;
    const yMargin = (image.bitmap.width * LOGO_MARGIN_PERCENTAGE) / 100;

    const X = image.bitmap.width - logo.bitmap.width - xMargin;
    const Y = image.bitmap.height - logo.bitmap.height - yMargin;

    image.composite(logo, X, Y, [
      {
        mode: Jimp.BLEND_SCREEN,
        opacitySource: 0.1,
        opacityDest: 1
      }
    ]);

    image.write('animatedimg.gif')
```

But it only works on image with filetype png/jpg/jpeg.
It doesn't work on gif image.

It will generate a file 'animatedimg.gif', but that file won't load to any image viewer or browser.

If I try to open that file in mac, the popup will appear with message:
"The file “animatedimg.gif” could not be opened because it is empty."

Is there any way to do that in jimp?
Or is there other npm package for that?
Thank you.

Comment: you'd need to process each frame of the GIF adding the watermark to each one ... does *jimp* have such functionality? perhaps [gifwrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifwrap) will help

Comment: @JaromandaX I will try that, thank you.

Comment: @JaromandaX Is there a way to read image from url using gifwrap?

Comment: sorry, I haven't read the documentation for gifwrap - there's something about it being useful *in conjunction with jimp* either in jimp or gifwrap documentation - read documentation and try things is all I'll say, because it's your project

Comment: @noyruto88 No, you'll have to do it yourself. Make an HTTP request, write that file to your file system, and then leverage `gifwrap` to read that file you just saved with `GifUtil.read`.

Answer (score 2):

Confusingly, Jimp only deals with *single frame* GIFs, not the multi-frame animated GIFs that most people think of. So you need to use [gifwrap](https://github.com/jtlapp/gifwrap).

From there you could iterate over each frame in the multi-frame GIF. Each frame is a `GifFrame`, which can be converted back and forth to a Jimp instance (see [Leveraging Jimp](https://github.com/jtlapp/gifwrap#leveraging-jimp) in the docs). You can add your watermark to each Jimp instance that corresponds to a `GifFrame`. Something like this:

```
async function getGifFramesWithWatermarks(gifPath) {
  const readGif = await GifUtil.read(gifPath);
  const promises = readGif.frames.map(getGifFrameWithWatermark);
  const gifFramesWithWatermarks = await Promise.all(promises);

  return gifFramesWithWatermarks;
}

async function getGifFrameWithWatermark(gifFrame) {
  const jimpImage = GifUtil.copyAsJimp(Jimp, gifFrame);

  addWatermark(jimpImage); // function you will write

  return new GifFrame(jimpImage.bitmap, {
    disposalMethod: gifFrame.disposalMethod, // not documented by gifwrap but it's in the source
    delayCentisecs: gifFrame.delayCentisecs, // you'll probably want this
  });
}

const gifFramesWithWatermarks = await getGifFramesWithWatermark(GIF_PATH);
await GifUtil.write(WRITE_PATH, gifFramesWithWatermarks);
```

Comment: can you please share a example

Comment: @AdamZerner how the addWatermark looks like?

Comment: @BrunoQuaresma That's a function that you will need to write using `jimp`. It's been a while since I've used it so I forget.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
i wrote this npm library that you can use to write text on gif. its still has some bugs tho: https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-on-gif

this worked for me

```
const Jimp = require("jimp");
const { GifUtil,GifFrame,BitmapImage} = require('gifwrap');
var frames = [];

Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE).then(async function(font){
    await GifUtil.read("gif.gif").then(inputGif => {
        inputGif.frames.forEach(function(frame){
            jimpCopied = GifUtil.copyAsJimp(Jimp, frame);
            jimpCopied.print(font,0,0,"sanidhya");
            const GifCopied = new GifFrame(new BitmapImage(jimpCopied.bitmap,{
                disposalMethod: frame.disposalMethod,
                delayCentisecs: frame.delayCentisecs,
            }));
        frames.push(GifCopied);   
        });
    });
    GifUtil.quantizeDekker(frames);
    GifUtil.write("nyahhaha.gif",frames);
});
```

**NOTE**

the qunatize*() function is needed only if your Frame uses more than 256 color indexes

Comment: This doesn't work with compressed gifs, only ones with each frame having all color data. It's also super slow.

Comment: @ThickMiddleManager i noticed, can you please suggest come changes to make it work??

Comment: You need to rerender the gif with imagemagick. I think Jimp is not the tool for this job unfortunately.

Comment: @ThickMiddleManager by rerender you mean using something like "im.convert()" ?

Comment: Hi, how would I preappend an iamge for multiple frames before my gif?